# Submitting a redirect with nested parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A controller normally handles parameters as

```
[:pack][:event_id]
```

To maintain coding consistency a seperate action needs to call the same commands via a private method.

Hoever, when creating a `redirect_to`,  how can this class/attribute compound be invoked?

```
redirect_to retry_packs_path(pack[event_id]: @genitore.event_id)
```

is generating `unexpected ':', expecting ')'`.

Comment: retry_packs_path(pack: { event_id: @genitore.event_id })

Comment: `redirect_to retry_packs_path("pack[event_id]" => @genitore.event_id)` or `redirect_to retry_packs_path(pack: { event_id: @genitore.event_id })`